# Need to make the site 'unaccessible'

Tags: site

I have a sharepoint site at the web-app level.
Time to time, that site should not be accessible until we decide to turn it on. During the period when it is down, if anyone tries to access, I would like capture some details as to who accessed it (IP address etc).

What are the best options (apart from going to IIS and stopping the site)?

If any custom coding is required, please suggest.

thanks.

Comment: Why not to use app_offline.html? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153449/asp-net-2-0-how-to-use-app-offline-htm

Comment: How to log if anyone has tried to access?   Also with the "offline_html" approach, will it work for someone who may have opened the site days back in a browser. I guess it should work, but wanted to confirm. thanks.

Comment: I believe you can use IIS logs to see if someone is trying to access the offline application.

Comment: Whole application is goes down, so if you don't have smth like Comet chats or other things which hold the connection open, all will be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If users are authenticated, and you are using AD you could restrict users to certain logon hours. I imagine you could probably log failed logon attempts at the domain controller.

Another option is to stick a reverse proxy server in front of your SharePoint server (e.g. ForeFront TMG) and add a rule to restrict access. User IP addresses, times etc. will be logged.

We use the latter option to prevent access during maintenance windows.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.  Would appreciate if you can point me to any working examples or samples. thanks again.

Comment: If you want a working example, our company Web site (http://www.eshareuk.com) is published using ISA Server 2006. We use a publishing rule to block requests to the site during maintenance windows. If you are after a step by step walkthrough of how to set this up, I blogged the steps for SP2010 / ISA 2006 at http://www.benjaminathawes.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=6. Note that this is only a basic example that doesn't include setting up a "maintenance" rule but it's quite straightforward once you are comfortable with ISA. These days you should use TMG instead of ISA.